# outerWidth/outerHeight is different when jquery.ui is included, ¿what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have an script that uses the function `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()`, the script was working very well before the use of the jquery.ui library. Now I'm not getting a value in (height/width) like (300/200), I'm getting an object for these "values" like: `[object Object]`

What I'm doing wrong? What's wrong? Thank you!

Before:

```
var height = $('#div').outerHeight(); // 455
var width = $('#div').outerWidth(); // 650
```

After:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>

var height = $('#div').outerHeight(); // [object Object]
var width = $('#div').outerWidth(); // [object Object]
```

What's the solution?

Comment: `$("#selector").outerWidth()` returns a valid number for me in jQueryUI 1.10.2

Comment: You can use some UI elements and they can change class (and style) of your div's

Comment: It would help diagnostics immensely if you could replicate the behaviour in a small example. You may even find that the exercise of trying to replicate the issue in a small example will reveal to you the cause of the issue.

Comment: Can confirm this behaviour with jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.21